# Hope to remove armv6 architecture for iPad in XCode?

Tags: xcode, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.2

When building an iPad only application I get the following warning:

**"warning: building for deployment target '3.2' should omit the armv6 architecture."**

I would like to edit the Architectures setting so it only shows armv7.  However, the options are coming from the following marco $(ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS).

Is there a macro I should be using for IPAD (non-universal) binaries.

To work around the problem I did the following:

1. Make sure active target is set on armv7

   Check the "Build Active Architecture Only" option

That removes the warning and creates a non-universal binary, but I have to do this EVERY time I switch configurations because the active target keeps defaulting to armv6.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about an appropriate macro, but if you select "other...", remove $(ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS), and enter just "armv7" on its own, that seems to do the trick.

Comment: The text from the Macro says "Optimized(armv6 armv7)".  So by just putting in armv7 is that going to be Optimized or "standard".  Would just putting in something like Optimized(armv7) work?.

Answer (score 2):

I deleted the arm6 entry, but my error never went away until I clicked the "Build for active architecture only" button.

Answer (score 1):

Bad idea. Jut removed arm6 and tried to upload my app to iTC. I get the following error:

"The binary you uploaded was invalid. When supporting iPhone, the executable must include support for the armv6 architecture, unless the UIRequireDeviceCapabilities include the 'armv7' capability."

I added it back in, rebuilt and strangely I don't get the warning any more. So maybe it was all about clicking off that "Build for Active Architecture" button.

Anyway, I'm uploading the new binary now